# Google-snappy compression produces larger size than original

Tags: c++, compression, snappy

I want to use google-snappy and I did some simple tests to familiarize with the library. I have written the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "snappy/snappy.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    static const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    std::string string_data, string_data_temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        string_data += alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
    }
        snappy::Compress(string_data.data(), string_data.size(),
                         &string_data_temp);

        std::cout << string_data.size() << std::endl;
        std::cout << string_data_temp.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So basically I generate a random string and then I compress it and measure its size. What is really interesting is that when I run the program `string_data` has a size of 10 and the compressed version `string_data_temp` has a size of 12. What is the explanation of this? Shouldn't the compressed version be at most the size of the original input even in the case of a random string?

Comment: No, [every lossless compression method has to make some inputs larger](http://matt.might.net/articles/why-infinite-or-guaranteed-file-compression-is-impossible/). Actually more like the majority of inputs. Because math.

Comment: And because snappy and LZ4 are very similar, the linked answer also applies.